# Event handler problem when feeding HTML chart via wix code

Tags: javascript, charts, eventhandler, velo

I'm feeding an HTML element (pie chart) on a wix page. I pull data from local storage for 7 variables and pass the information to the HTML element via Postmessage.

My code works fine when it's part of a button (export function). However I would like to trigger the event from the onReady function (i.e. when the page is loaded). I use the exact same code but it simply doesn't work with the OnReady function (i.e. I'm unable to trigger the event programatically).

Wix pagecode for Export Function with button (works fine):

```
export function button1_click(event) {
var data = [introdeo, intcalypso, intbalthazar, intluna, intkiara, intmistral, intsaya];
console.log(data);
var labels = ["Rodeo", "Calypso", "Balthazar", "Luna", "Kiara", "Mistral", "Saya"];
let info = {data:data, labels:labels};
$w("#html1").postMessage(info);
}
```

Wix pagecode for onReady function (doesn't work):

```
$w.onReady(function () {
var data = [introdeo, intcalypso, intbalthazar, intluna, intkiara, intmistral, intsaya];
var labels = ["Rodeo", "Calypso", "Balthazar", "Luna", "Kiara", "Mistral", "Saya"];
let info = {data:data, labels:labels};
$w("#html1").postMessage(info); 

} );
```

HTML code (the chart code in the HTML element on wix page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>


<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels:[],
        datasets: [{
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: ["#f97a03", "#52aff0", "#35a11d", "#f052e4", "#853fc2", "#f0f712", "#092978"],
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});

window.onmessage = function(event){
    myPieChart.data.datasets[0].data = event.data.data;
    myPieChart.data.labels = event.data.labels;
    myPieChart.update();
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

With the button Export function, I get an updated pie chart on my web page. With the OnReady code, I get a blank space in the HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the html element might not be ready to receive that POST. Try wrapping `$w("#html1").postMessage(info);` in a setTimeout.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  var data = [introdeo, intcalypso, intbalthazar, intluna, intkiara, intmistral, intsaya];
  var labels = ["Rodeo", "Calypso", "Balthazar", "Luna", "Kiara", "Mistral", "Saya"];
  let info = {data:data, labels:labels};
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#html1").postMessage(info);
  }, 1000) 
});
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked initially. Then I published the change, and it doesn't work anymore. When I click "preview", I briefly see the chart, and then it's gone. Also there is a difference between the preview mode and the live website. On the live website, my function button brigns the chart but with the wrong values. There is something wrong with either my Page code or HTML code or both!

Comment: Tough for me to say without knowing all the code you have in there...but for me all I did was take your code, paste it in, wrap the set timeout and it worked as expected. In preview mode and after [publish](https://sjstgermain.wixsite.com/mysite)

Comment: I changed to 2000 milliseconds and it works! However... I get Calypso 0, Balthazar 5, Luna 1, Kiara 4, Mistral 2, Rodeo 8 and Saya 4 in Preview mode (which is correct) and Calypso 3, Balthazar 4, Luna 3, Kiara 6, Mistral 4, Rodeo 3 and Saya 0 on the live website, which is incorrect! How is that possible? thanks,

Comment: You're getting the variables from local storage, they could be different between the two environments...tough for me know without knowing how they are set, etc. When you were using your button approach I am assuming the data was as expected?

Comment: Also--as a side note--you are in race condition with the setTimeout approach...2 seconds might always work out, but there might be a time when it doesn't.  ideally `onReady` would not fire until your iFrame was ready.

Comment: The proper way to get around this is for the HTML Component to send a message to the page when it has finished loading. Only then will the page send the data to the HTML Element. That way you don't have to guess how long it's going to take using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use a promise 
and resolve the promise when the HTMl component is ready to use

So, in this code we are sending the data for every 500ms to check if the HTML is ready
and if it's ready updating the global variable and resolving the promise

```js
$w.onReady(()=>{
let isHTMLready = false;

    async function sendHTMLData() {
        await isHTMLReady(); // this line will wait until the HTML component is ready
        // then your code here
    }

    $w('#htmlID').onmessage(e=>{
        let {data} = e;
        if(data.isReady) {
            // html is ready 
            isHTMLReady = true; //updating the gloable variable
        } else if(data.someOtherCondition) {
            // do something
        }
    });

    function isHTMLReady() {
        return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
            let i = 0;
            let intervalID = setInterval(()=>{
                $w('#html').postMessage({
                    isHTMLReady : true
                });
                if(isHTMLready) { // checking if the global variable is changed to true
                    // stop the time interval
                    clearInterval(intervalID);
                    // resolve the promise
                    res("ready");
                }
                i++;
                if(i > 28) { // waiting until 14 second before rejecting the promise
                    // rejecting the promise
                    rej("no response from HTML");
                }
            },500);
        });
    }
    
});
```

on the HTML component add this following code
It will check if the data sent is "isHTMLReady" then (if the HTML component is ready) we will send it back to wix site
from there we will update the variable and stop the interval and resolve the promise

```js
window.onmessage = e => {
    let {data} = e;
    if(data.isHTMLReady) {
        messageWixSite({isHTMLReady: true});
    }
    else if(data.isGraphData) {
        // write your code here
    }
}

function messageWixSite(data) {
    let msg = {
        "isCropper" : true,
    }
    msg = {...msg, ...data};
    // console.log("message : " , msg);
    window.parent.postMessage(msg, "*");
}
```

This way we ensure that both the wix site and the HTML element is ready to use before sending the data